# Hibernate update specific object in a List

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc

How can I update a specific object in a list? The situation is as follows:
I have entity **Distributor**  with field

```
@LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.FALSE)
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy="distributor", orphanRemoval=true)
    List<Exhibitor> exhibitor = new ArrayList<Exhibitor>();
```

Every Exhibitor object has status (available | not available) which I want to update from a select box in jsp.
The problem is when I fetch the Exhibitor entity by ID, and call update on this object, I receive an empty row with only the updated status.

What is the correct method to perform update on a list with objects ?

Comment: What does this mean: 
`I receive an empty row with only the updated status.` ?

Comment: This means that, instead to update the status.. new row in the entity table Exhibitor is created with the updated status .. :)